# Corrigir CLS em imagens dinâmicas

Tags: html, imagem, layout-responsivo, layout

Um dos principais problemas enfrentados no Lighthouse do Google é a questão do CLS. Nos meus clientes isso é algo que acontece com muita frequência.

Sei que para corrigir o CLS a melhor alternativa é setar o tamanho nas imagens usando os atributos `width` e `height`, no entanto, meus clientes fazem uso de várias imagens(cadastradas por eles mesmos) que possuem tamanhos/proporções diferentes o que acaba impossibilitando setar os tamanhos na tag `<img>`

Uma alternativa que encontrei foi usar o `data-sizes="auto"` que é nativo do [Lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)(plugin que uso para fazer lazyload), porém sem muito sucesso pelo fato de não resolver plenamente o problema.

Em alguns artigos vi uma sugestão de usar o aspect-ratio, onde ele faria uso dos atributos `width` e `height` usados na tag `<img>`, mas como citado não tenho essas informações disponíveis

```
img {
  aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma alternativa para resolver esse problema

Comment: Acho a pergunta boa, só precisa elaborar um [mcve]. Sobre o assunto, acho interessante, apesar da minha clara visão sobre entender que muitas "técnicas" são meios de contornar problemas que nem deveriam existir, mas já falei muito dos muitos erros que o mundo front-end decidiram adotar como soluções para depois ter que criar outras soluções para resolver o problema de antes ... ainda sim discutir sobre [web-vitals](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) me parece necessário. Vou deixar +1, mas espero que forneça um código minimo reproduzivel, ficamos no aguardo.